# Todas as sílabas devem possuir pelo menos uma vogal?

Tags: ortografia, vocabulário, fonemas, separação-silábica

Na separação de sílabas, por exemplo:

> Palavra = pa - la - vra
>   Boneca = bo - ne - ca

Todas as sílabas devem possuir uma vogal?

Nota-se, nestes exemplos, que cada sílaba possui uma vogal.
Podem existir sílabas com mais de uma vogal?

Comment: De sílabas sem vogais, só lembro de palavras de origem estrangeira. De sílabas com mais de uma vogal, basta olhar para a palavra "vo-g**ai**s".

Comment: "**Cai**-xe-ta"

Comment: Na escritura e língua padrão? Ou na fala quotidiana? À primeira a resposta é sim, à segunda, não.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>(Tem diferenças na terminologia linguística, e eu vou apresentar só *uma* versão (simplificada).)</sub>

#### Todas as sílabas devem possuir uma vogal?

Sim. Tecnicamente, uma sílaba é composta de

- *onset*
- *núcleo*
- *coda*

Em outras palavras, uma sílaba tem uma decomposição *onset|**núcleo**|coda*, por exemplo

> P|**o**|r . t|**u**| . gu|**ê**|s
>   |**á**| . gu|**a**|
>   |**á**|r . v|**o**| . r|**e**|

Em Português o núcleo é sempre uma vogal. (Em outras idiomas, o núcleo pode ser uma consoante silábica, mas não existe tal consoante na língua Portuguesa.) Cada sílaba tem núcleo, então, cada sílaba possui uma vogal. (Mas existem sílabas, que não têm *onset* (|**á**|r) ou *coda* (v|**o**|), ou não têm ambos (|**á**|).)

#### Podem existir sílabas com mais de uma vogal?

Podem sim, se a definição de "vogal" é como uma *letra* (A, E, I, ...). O núcleo de uma sílaba é sempre uma vogal só, mas podem existir vogais no *onset* ou na *coda*, por exemplo

> |**U**| – r|**u**| – gu|**a**|i

Nesse caso a sílaba é ditado de possuir um ditongo ou tritongo. As vogais do *onset* ou *coda* de uma sílaba são chamados de *semivogais* ou *consoantes aproximantes* e são pronuciadas como "consoantes"

> U.ru.guai → [u.ɾu.g**w**a**j**]

então também tem razão dizendo que (fonologicamente) toda sílaba só tem uma vogal.

---

*Referências*.

- Wikipédia [Semivogal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semivogal) e [Syllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable) (*ing.*)
- C.M. Ignácio de Mendoça, "A sílaba em fonologia", *Working papers em lingüística*, UFSC, N. 7, 2003. ([pdf](https://periodicos.ufsc.br/index.php/workingpapers/article/viewFile/6165/5720))

Comment: Anhanguera é uma palavra desconhecida em Portugal; nem sequer imaginei que o u fosse lido (ü). Seria talvez melhor usar outro exemplo, por exemplo "aguaceiro" ou "quais", ou...

Comment: Excelente resposta, valeu a pena esperar.

Answer (score 14):

## Todas as sílabas devem possuir uma vogal?

Sim. Na língua portuguesa, o núcleo da sílaba é sempre uma vogal.

## Pode existir sílabas com mais de uma vogal?

Sim, [em todos os ditongos, por exemplo](http://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/ditongos-tritongos-e-hiatos-encontros-vocalicos.htm).

Answer (score 3):

**Todas as sílabas devem possuir uma vogal?**

Sim, toda sílaba deve possuir uma vogal.

**Podem existir sílabas com mais de uma vogal?**

Tecnicamente, não. Uma sílaba só pode ter uma vogal.

No caso de ditongos parecem existir duas vogais em uma sílaba mas na verdade uma delas é vogal e a outra semi-vogal.

Por exemplo: A-MEI-XA
Ameixa é uma palavra de três sílabas com um ditongo decrescente (ou seja, a primeira vogal do ditongo é a dominante). Nesse caso E é vogal e I é semi-vogal.

EDIT:

Ter uma, e apenas uma, vogal é condição sine qua non da sílaba já que ela é definida pela vogal. Todas outras letras da sílaba são acessórias à vogal e apenas à complementam. 
O ponto mais confuso são os encontros vocálicos.
No caso de ditongos e tritongos as letras /i/ ou /u/ se tornam semi-vogais, ficando em segundo plano (foneticamente), servindo apenas de acessório à vogal que é parte principal da sílaba.
No caso dos hiatos temos duas vogais juntas na palavra mas pela mesma regra elas formam duas sílabas distintas já que não podem existir duas (ou mais) vogais em uma só sílaba.

Exemplos:
Ditongo crescente (a segunda letra do ditongo é a vogal):
Sé-rie

Ditongo decrescente (a primeira letra do ditongo é a vogal):
Pai

Reparem como na fala a vogal é muito mais presente do que a semi-vogal.

Ao se pronunciar Pai o /i/ mal aparece, sendo apenas um acessório ao /a/ que domina a sílaba.
No caso de sé-rie observa-se o oposto. O /i/ fica em segundo plano.

No caso de um hiato ambas as vogais são bem pronunciadas e portanto pertencem a sílabas distintas. 
Ex.: Em "Sa-í-da" o /i/ é pronunciado distintamente. Isso acontece graças ao acento agudo, se o /i/ não fosse acentuado a palavra seria "sai-da", com o /a/ sendo vogal e o /i/ semi-vogal (obs.: até onde eu sei "saida" não existe).

Comment: Poderias colocar alguma referência explicitando melhor o que é uma semi-vogal e porque uma sílaba não pode ter 2 vogais?

Comment: Infelizmentenão tenho o conhecimento técnico para uma explicação mais "acadêmica" mas vou editar a resposta para contemplar teu comentário.

Comment: -1: uma semivogal [**é** uma vogal](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/semivogal).

Comment: Mas, e no caso da palavra `quais`? "Ai" é um ditongo, mas "u" não é parte do ditongo. Quantas vogais tem então a palavra `quais`? :)

Comment: Depende da definição de vogal. As letras A E I O U são as vogais da língua portuguesa mas na sílaba  podem ser vogais ou semi-vogais. Ou seja, depende do critério. Mas ao se falar em sílaba só existe uma vogal.

Comment: **quais** contém um tritongo. Assim como U-RU-GUAI. Por mais estranho que pareça **quais** só tem uma sílaba.

Comment: +1, mas talvez seria melhor dar a definição de uma sílaba e explicar que o núcleo é composto de ou uma vogal ou uma consoante silábica. Eu acho que, tecnicamente, uma sílaba pode ser composto de dois ou três vogais, mas só uma funciona como núcleo, e o(s) outro(s) são semivogais.

Comment: @LucasKunzler a [definição de semivogal](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/semivogal) diz que ela **é** uma vogal; portanto, um ditongo *tem duas vogais* (sendo que apenas uma delas é o "núcleo"). Essa definição está errada? Gostava de ver a contra-definição que diz que uma semivogal *não* é uma vogal.

Comment: @ANeves Tentei explicar a diferença na [minha reposta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/692/64).

Comment: @Earthliŋ sim, já tinha visto, obrigado; é uma resposta de muito alta qualidade. :)